# Cannot execute Azure Functions on VS Code

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a Javascript Azure Function on VS Code, but I'm getting an error on npm.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
> Executing task: npm install <

env: node: No such file or directory
The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'npm install'" failed to launch (exit code: 127).
```

I'm on a MacOS machine, and my node and npm versions are:

```
- node: v12.18.3
- npm: 6.14.6
```

I already re-installed node and npm on my machine and already exported the /usr/local/bin folder on the path variable.

The error happens only when I click on the debugging button in vs code. If I run my function using func start, everything works fine.

Any advices on how to solve this?

Comment: VS Code is just a tool, basically VS Code also run func host start. So please show the   settings of VS:extension.json, launch.json, settings.json, tasks.json.

Comment: Are you using nvm? If so, this [faq](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_why-is-nvm-complaining-about-a-prefix-option-when-the-integrated-terminal-is-launched) does talk about issues on MacOS.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?